# Writing audit trail funtionality in postgres, can I use pl/V8 instead of pl/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm using postgres 9.4 on Amazon RDS.

This the fast and loose "application developer" definition of an audit trail.
The audit trail isn't for security nor is it a legal requirement - I don't even plan on putting it in a different schema.
It's purely for visibility of "who did what, when" so I can answer questions from the business; where our generic for "created by / last updated by" columns won't quite cut it.

The application is a standard multi-tier JVM-based line-of-business app.  It's never going to need to hit any kind of real scale.
Our requirements could probably be satisfied by writing interceptor-style functionality in the application tier.  Been there, done that, wasn't very hard - but it has its downsides and I want to do it in the database this time.
Initially, there's not even any plans to build any user-level query functionality, when we need to figure out what happened to some piece of data we'll do it by hand - maybe even offline.

I'm thinking triggers that dump the changes into a jsonb column.  Basically port https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus to pl/V8 with jsonb, plus my own unique brand of weirdness thrown in for flavour.
I know pg_audit is coming, but it won't make it in time for what I'm doing.  Besides, it appears that it will have a bunch of complexity to satisfy a host of requirements that I'm not interested in.

My understanding is that RDS offers pl/V8 by default, so would it be a terrible idea to do this in V8?
I'm looking here for *concrete reasons* that would make doing this in V8 objectively inferior to pgSQL.

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable, I don't see why it's a concern.

Comment: That example audit trigger seems way to complex for a business requirement to answer "who did what, when". I'd look at http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/ instead.

Comment: yeah - that does look a lot simpler, thanks.